# iPhone OpenGL-ES: Adding a texture to one face of a cube

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

building a 3D environment, So far I have fully textured cubes and colored cubes.  What I want to do is add a texture to one of the Coloured cube faces

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &colourCubeVertexFaces[0]);

glColor4ub(colourCubeFaceColors[colorIndex], colourCubeFaceColors[colorIndex+1], colourCubeFaceColors[colorIndex+2], colourCubeFaceColors[colorIndex+3]);glColor4ub(colourCubeFaceColors[colorIndex], colourCubeFaceColors[colorIndex+1], colourCubeFaceColors[colorIndex+2], colourCubeFaceColors[colorIndex+3]);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &colourCubeVertexFaces[6]);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &colourCubeVertexFaces[12]);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &colourCubeVertexFaces[18]);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &colourCubeVertexFaces[24]);
```

I thought it would be as easy as turning on (and off)

```
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
```

Then Bind a texture

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ([[coordsArray objectAtIndex:4] floatValue]));
```

and then plotting it

```
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texturedCubeCoord);
```

But it just seems to slow down alot and not show anything.  My other fully textured cubes are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)